# Declaring macro variable with evaluation of function as value

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS. I encurred into a problem when trying to declare a macro variable with the result of some operation as value.

`data _null_;
%let var1 = 12345;
%let var2 = substr(&var1., 4,5);
run;`

I get that `var2` has value `substr(&var1., 4,5)` (a string) instead of `45` as I would like. How to make the variable declaration evaluate the function?

Sorry it the question is trivial. I looked in the documentation for a bit but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Just an FYI - in case you want to use a function (non macro equivalents), you can use `%sysfunc()` to encase the function and arguments. For example - `%sysfunc(substr(&var1., 4,5))` would work the same way as `%substr(&var1., 4,2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a macro equivalent called `%substr()` which can be used as follows:

```
%let var1 = 12345;
%let var2 = %substr(&var1., 4,2);

%put var2 = &var2;
```

Note that the `data` and `run` statements are not required for macro language processing and the 3rd argument to `%substr()` (and `substr()`) specifies the length you want, not the position of the last character, which is why I used `2` instead of `5`.

Edit: Also, if there is no macro equivalent then you could use `%sysfunc()` to make use of the data step function in macro code. See the [documention](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1o13d7wb2zfcnn19s5ssl2zdxvi.htm) for full details as there are some quirks, such as not using quotes and a few exceptions to the list of data step functions that can be used.